# Getting Client Ip on NODE.JS Through Cloudflare

Tags: node.js, ip, cloudflare

I am currently using
data["ip"] = socket.client.conn.remoteAddress;;
But this will only show me the cloudflare IPs and I am not a fan of leaking my server's ip so how can I get my client's ip through cloudflare?

Comment: What type of connection is this from the client?  HTTP?  socket.io?  plain webSocket?

Comment: It is kinda both but socket.io through TCP / HTTPS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After me having to research for a couple of good hours I found out.

socket.client.request.headers['cf-connecting-ip']

Comment: You saved me bunch of more hours I'm sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1387) says that in socket.io 1+, you should be using:

```
socket.request.connection.remoteAddress
```

or:

```
socket.handshake.address
```

But, if there are cloudfare proxy servers in the path (which there presumably are), then this will only report the true client IP address if the cloudfare proxy servers set the appropriate header to the actual client IP address when they proxy the initial HTTP connection that initiates the socket.io connection.

Comment: It still ends up giving me the cloudflare Ips...
data["ip"] = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress; // http://i.imgur.com/ZfjoZnF.png

Comment: @Predator - Then, the issue is with cloudFare.  As I said in my answer, in order to see the actual client IP, a proxy has to pass that IP address through in a standard way (as a specific HTTP header) because the actual TCP connection your server sees is from the proxy, not from the client.

Comment: Well cloudflare does have their own header so how can I use it to get the client's ip?

Comment: @Predator - `socket.handshake.headers` will contain the headers from the original connection request so if cloudFare is putting the original IP address into a header, it should be in the `socket.handshake.headers` object.