# Sentry capturing Cloudflare IP instead of client IP

Tags: angular, cloudflare, sentry

**Background:** Sentry integration is working except, it's capturing Cloudflare IP instead of client IP.

**What I tried to do:**
Is to use Client IP instead of Cloudflare IP for sentry log. Example:
[image: current sentry log]

**What I've tried:**
Using Cloudflare worker HTML Rewriter (https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/html-rewriter/) to pass `request.headers.get("x-real-ip")` or `request.headers.get("cf-connecting-ip")` into app and used the data in app to setup sentry like:

```
Sentry.setUser({
     ip_address: document.querySelector("[data-key=ip]")?.innerHTML.trim()
});
```

**Current Problem:** I managed to get Client IP using the HTML Rewriter method. But sentry still logs Cloudflare IP which lead me into asking whether using `Sentry.setUser` ip_address is incorrect or I miss any CF configurations.

Does anyone have idea as to what I'm missing?

Resource I found:

- [Getting Client Ip on NODE.JS Through Cloudflare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927749/getting-client-ip-on-node-js-through-cloudflare) (it's on node which kinda similar with how current worker IP fetch)
- https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/troubleshooting/restoring-visitor-ips/restoring-original-visitor-ips/ (doesn't help since it's server configs)

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this!